# Given $\csc{x \text{ } \frac{dy}{dx}}=xy$, express $y$ in terms of $x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I do this?

> Given $\csc{x \text{ } \frac{dy}{dx}}=xy$, express $y$ in terms of $x$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1mH8.png

I got $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{xy}{\csc{x}}$, then how can I remove the $y$? I am thinking maybe I need to use substitution or something?

**UPDATE: Correct Working?**

Is my working correct?

[image]

Comment: This differential equation is easily solved using [Separation of Variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables).

Comment: Also, $1/\csc(x)=\sin(x)$

Comment: use $csc (x) =1/sin(x)$ and integrate...

Comment: You need to keep the "+C" throughout.

Comment: @DavidMitra, so its $y=e^{-x \cos{x} + \sin{x}}+C$? does $v$ need a $+C$ too?

Comment: @jiewmeng $y=e^{-x\cos x+\sin x+C}=e^C\cdot e^{-x\cos x+\sin x}$ is the answer. No, $v$ dosesn't need it. Add the constant after you finish integrating by parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: The technique you need to use here is called "Separation of Variables". The idea is that for the differential equation $ \frac{dy}{dx} = f(x,y) $, in the special case where we can write $f$ as a product of functions of $x$ and $y$ separately, i.e $f(x,y) = h(x)g(y) $, then we write the equation in the form $$ \frac{dy}{g(y) } = h(x) dx .$$

Then we have only a single variable on each side, and we integrate both sides. So here, we should write $$\int \frac{dy}{y} = \int x \sin x dx ,$$  evaluate the integrals, and then solve for $y.$ The left integral is simply a natural log, while the integral on the right can be found by integration by parts.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Rewrite it as $\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{y} = x \sin(x) \mathrm{d} x$, which is equivalent to $\int \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{y} = \int x \sin(x) \mathrm{d} x + C$. Can you evaluate these integrals ? Then use initial conditions to determined the integration constant $C$.